# Issue with attaching an Image file with mail

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to capture a view as an image and then attach that image through mail , but the problem is after capturing the view a white border appears around the image ! , this problem happens only on **iPhone 5** device ! here is my code :

**Sharing.m**

```
- (void)mailAttachmentWithImage:(UIView*)view openInView:(UIViewController*)viewCont {

    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    UIView* captureView = view;
    captureView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    /* Capture the screen shoot at native resolution */
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(captureView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [captureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    /* Render the screen shot at custom resolution */
    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 ,1024 ,1024);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size, NO, 1.0f);
    [screenshot drawInRect:cropRect];
    UIImage * customScreenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(customScreenShot);
    [controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Image"];


    [viewCont presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

**ViewController.m**

and then capture view :

```
- (IBAction)mail:(id)sender {


 [shareIt mailAttachmentWithImage:_captureView openInView:self];

}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information about the view that you are capturing. Screenshot of that view pre-capture?

Comment: @AlfieHanssen check out my edited question , it just happens on iPhone 5 !!! it's really weird !!!

Comment: Is the image in your post (the picture of the guy) the screenshot you captured? Or the view that you are capturing from? At a surface level I'd guess that you are capturing a bounding box that's larger than the image itself, yielding a white border. If it's just happening on iPhone 5 does that mean it's not happening on another device?

Comment: @AlfieHanssen NO ! its captured image ! this is what happens ! a white border appears around the image

Comment: Maybe worth a try...   [customScreenShot.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]]; - this sets the layers borderColor to clear.

Comment: @JohnWoods customScreenShot is UIImage data not UIImageView

Comment: Can you try this on the uiview though?  [captureView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];

Comment: @JohnWoods I tried , same result

Comment: Not only I should down-vote you for your not very good question. I should also down-vote you for the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved ! because my View was bigger than targeted image size !!!!

Comment: its of no help to others!

Comment: please give more info about the solution in your anwser

Answer (score 2):

you need to capture image of `Image-view` instead of `UIView`. your posted answer is not enough to help's Other. as my bellow code you can capture image of your `Image-view` Frame try with Bellow code:-

```
-(void)imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
      CGRect rect = CGRectMake(imgview.frame.origin.x, imgview.frame.origin.y,imgview.frame.size.width, imgview.frame.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, YES, 1.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


   // CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,10,10);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([screenshot CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *croppedScreenshot = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(croppedScreenshot);

   [controller addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Image"];
   [viewCont presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

So this Captured image not contain Border and you can attach this image Without Border in to E-mail.